# Wordpress Multisite Siteurl & home setup creating odd paths. Why?

Tags: wordpress

As always thanks in advance if you can help.

I'm seeing a very weird issue with a multisite. Currently it has the following multisites setup:

```
www.domain.com
www.domain.com/london/
www.domain.com/paris/
www.domain.com/berlin/
```

Each subdirectory site uses a different child theme (containing a few changes to css in each) of www.domain.com overiding theme.

The network sites each have the setup options for Siteurl and Home, which each reflect the setup of:

```
Siteurl:www.domain.com
Home:www.domain.com/london/
```

This works fine, but BREAKS the backend navigation for the /london/ website trying to force all wordpress links as www.domain.com/wp-admin rather than www.domain.com/london/wp-admin.

I changed the network setup of each website to the equivalent of:

```
Siteurl:www.domain.com/london/
Home:www.domain.com/london/
```

This fixes the navigation for the backend of www.domain.com/london/wp-admin but breaks all path files for calling anything from the parent theme and breaks all css/images in the backend of wordpress.

This is dricing me crazy! Anyone else seen anything like this before?

Comment: Ok I'm starting to suspect this is a wp-config issue. Will investigate further...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer to this if anyone finds this was that our server was running NGINX without us realising which caused some pretty weird conflicts with the wordpress url re-writing. We simply turned it off and just run the server with stand alone Apache and it worked!